# How to check wheather specified port is available for communication?

Tags: java, networking

I am using Java Secure Channel to connect with hosts in a network.
I am using following code:

```
int port = 22;JSch jsch = new JSch();
try {
session=jsch.getSession(username,hostname,port);
}
catch (JSch Exception e1){
e1.printStackTrace();
}
session.setPassword("mypassword");
try {
session.connect();
}catch (JSchException e1){
System.out.println("Did not connect");
return;
}
```

By using this code I am able to connect to host.
But if host is unavailable/offline then I have to wait for JSchException.

1) I want to first check whether host is available for communication or not and if available then only try to connect.

2) Also I want to set timeout for connection,if connection doesn't established within that time interval must give exception.

How to check if host is available? and set timeout for connection?

Answer (score 1):

Testing before connecting makes no big sense, as port can become unavailable right after test. Try to use session.setTimeout() to set timeout in millis.

Answer (score 0):

> How to check whether specified port is available for communication?

How to check whether specified *X* is available for *Y:*

*Try to use it* for *Y.* It's an infallible test. Any other technique has timing-window problems.